# PUT page to OneNote via live-sdk

Tags: onenote, live-sdk

The Beta API provides two different end points for getting the content of a OneNote page from Live, one using the ContentUrl and one the Id. Both work. The GET looks as if it should work in the same way to replace a page by using a PUT instead (it's not documented as doing this, I'm guessing)

```
PUT https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/pages/{pageId}/content
```

but I get a 404 if I try this, using he same Id I've just successfuly used for a GET. Can one replace an entire page?

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PUT operations aren't yet supported on the OneNote API. We do support PATCH operations on a page to update specific elements. More information can be found at 
[OneNote PATCH reference documentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2014/11/06/new-beta-api-page-update.aspx) and [OneNote PATCH blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2014/11/06/new-beta-api-page-update.aspx)

Feel free to add a request for the PUT operation at https://onenote.uservoice.com

Comment: Thank you. I shall put in a request as it's needed for some of the things I have in mind. In the meantime, I shall look at patches (all looking good so far). A

Comment: One thing to note is that the GET api isn't 100% full fidelity yet (e.g. no ink), so doing a PUT would be a bit risky that you'd zap a user's ink annotations.  That's why we did PATCH first.

Comment: Ah, thanks GarethJ, currently that won't matter but good to be forewarned.